# SQL SELECT query not working

Tags: sql

```
SELECT s1.id, 
       s3.food_name, 
       Count(*) AS TotalRefill 
FROM   (SELECT ( s1.food_value - s2.food_value ) AS difference 
        FROM   `serving_info` s1, 
               `serving_info` s2 
        WHERE  s1.id - s2.id = '1' 
               AND s1.food_name = 'Shrimp' 
               AND s2.food_name = 'Shrimp') AS diff, 
       `serving_info` s3 
WHERE  s3.id = diff.id 
       AND s3.food_value >= '990' 
       AND diff.difference >= '150'
```

Result: `#1054 - Unknown column 's1.id' in 'field list'`

```
--
-- Table structure for table `employees`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `confirmcode` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
  KEY (name)
);
--
-- Table structure for table `Foods`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Foods` (
  `Food_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `CostPerRefill` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Food_name`)
);


--
-- Table structure for table `Serving_Info`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Serving_Info` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Food_Value` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Food_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Served_On` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Oncall` varchar(128),
  Foreign key(`Oncall`) REFERENCES `employees`(`name`),
  Foreign key(`Food_name`) REFERENCES `Foods`(`Food_name`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE (`Oncall`,`Food_name`, `Served_On`)
);
```

What is causing the s1 to not be declared? For some reason the s1 instance isn't detected by the s1.id. I have been trying to figure out from a while by changing different brackets but I really cannot figure out how to debug this..I have tried changing the position of the close bracket but that would mess up the query.

Comment: try just `SELECT id, food_name` in the first part because s1 and s3 are out of scope - they're in another select statement

Comment: You'd also need to add s1.id to the select list of your derived table.

Comment: You've encapsulated `s1` and `s2` into a subquery and called it `diff`.  If you want to use columns from that query, you need to use the `diff` prefix.

Comment: yah, he needs to have those in his sub-query for sure. though even with them in it the first `s1` and `s3` won't work

Comment: My teaching assistant helped me form that query during a help session and I have no idea how to fix it because even after adding diff.id instead of s1.id I start getting more errors...I feel like this entire query is broken and useless..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What all others here said is right, but just to give you a more preceise solution, look at the query below it should not be s1.id but it should be diff.id

```
SELECT diff.id, 
       s3.food_name, 
       Count(*) AS TotalRefill 
FROM   (SELECT ( s1.food_value - s2.food_value ) AS difference, s1.id 
        FROM   `serving_info` s1, 
               `serving_info` s2
        WHERE  s1.id - s2.id = '1' 
               AND s1.food_name = 'Shrimp' 
               AND s2.food_name = 'Shrimp') AS diff, 
       `serving_info` s3 
WHERE  s3.id = diff.id 
       AND s3.food_value >= '990' 
       AND diff.difference >= '150'
```

Comment: I had given up..Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

S1is defined inside the parentheses and thus not visible outside them, where you reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Because s1 is only defined in the inner select so not is scope.  Select either diff.id or s3.id (they will be the same value as you are joining on it).

Answer (score 0):

The table s1 is not in the from part of your query in which you are trying to select it, it's only in a subquery.